# Google Drive with github: share repository and drive folder

Tags: git, github

I am part of a small team and we usually collaborate using Google Drive. We share a Google Drive folder where we create and modify our codes.

We would like to use Github in addition to Google drive because it will be easier to track the different versions of the code.

Is it possible to share a single Google drive folder and use it as the repository as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use GitHub, just stick to GitHub.  It will offer you the ability to track code changes with the added benefit of allowing everyone to have a copy of the code base on their own machine via Git.

It works better than collaboration with cloud-driven systems since they don't offer any recourse against a change from someone else's machine wiping out your changes.